# Reconfigure ATMega328p registers

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, atmega328p

So I'm working with an ATMega328P. I'm trying to write a stepper driver to drive a DRV8825 breakout board. This requires only a single PWM. In order to properly accelerate the stepper motor I need to change the frequency of the PWM. I have the PWM running. I try to change the values stored in the Output Compare Registers to increase the frequency of the PWM. However this doesn't seem to work. I've tried reconfiguring all of the registers required to setup that PWM to output on PB2 however that doesn't seem to help. So I'm wondering if it is even possible to reconfigure a micocontroller's register after they are initially configured?

Comment: PWM uses a fixed frequency, and PFM is not commonly used to drive motors.

Comment: The output compare register controls the PWM period; to control frequency you need to change the count register or the prescalar.  Practically, for stepper motor drive ideas on an ATmega you might want to look at open source 3d printer firmwares, since those represent a lot of people's attempt to make the most of this popular if somewhat limited platform.

Comment: Yes are you correct PWM does use a fixed frequency. However using different values for the output compare registers can result in a PWM with differing frequencies. If I look for a compare at 10 my frequency will be two times that of the frequency obtained by looking for a compare at 20. I really appreciate both of your replies. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that there are two output compare registers per timer/counter. Regular PWM uses one OCR to control the duty cycle. However, you can configure the other OCR to clear the timer on a compare match (CTC mode). This has the effect of changing the PWM frequency because the timer will count up to a higher or lower value independent of the duty cycle.